# Why is CPU usage higher in Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04 via windows installer?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, wubi, performance

For normal usage, CPU consumption is above 80% for windows 7. This happened only after installing Ubuntu 12.04 via windows installer.

Why is it so?

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to Ubuntu, but just to be sure: Can you post a screenshot of the taskmanager where you have your processes sorted on cpu usage?

Comment: The only way this could happen is if you used up all your free space with the Wubi install and Windows is choking with paging. There's no part of Wubi that runs in Windows except during the install or the uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in a comment:

> The only way this could happen is if you used up all your free space
>   with the Wubi install and Windows is choking with paging. There's no
>   part of Wubi that runs in Windows except during the install or the
>   uninstall.

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Jan 12 at 2:54](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239873/why-is-cpu-usage-higher-in-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-via-windows-i#comment299467_239873)